# Spring Boot - using JPA Repositories with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot application with the following auto-configuration properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mywebapp
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

These work fine and I'm able to setup Spring Data [JpaRepositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html):

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>
{
    User findByName(String name);
}
```

...for the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    protected String uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;
}
```

...and use them like this:

```
@Transactional
public void updatePassword(String username, String password)
{
    User user = userRepository.findByName(username);
    user.setEmail("test@example.com"); // This gets persisted automatically by the JpaRepository.
}
```

Now I'm struggling to configure the same thing manually. I've tried the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig
{
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mywebapp");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.persistent");

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

...but while no exceptions are thrown and i can now successfully *read* from the database, it seems that none of the changes I make to the entities are being *persisted*.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing for the persistence to work?

Comment: at the first look it looks ok. Were you able to persist data before using the manually configuration? And can you show your repository and the class where you want to persist data.

Comment: Just curious, why are you interested in a manual configuration?

Comment: @Patrick I've now added the repository+entity.

Comment: If you are using JPA, why is there SessionFactory in there?

Comment: How do you persist automaticilly? Can you show this code?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Currently for learning purposes, mostly :) But I'll eventually need to fiddle with exotic hibernate properties that can't all be autowired.

Comment: Calling `EntityManager#merge` or `save` should be wrapped inside transaction, is your service method marked as `@Transactional`?

Comment: Where do you save your `user` entity? Anywhere you need to save it: `userRepository.save(user)`

Comment: @NeilStockton I must be misunderstanding: my thinking was that the EntityManager uses the session internally, thus I need to provide one for the JpaRepository to work. (I'll try providing an EntityManager instead!)

Comment: @glhr all hibernate properties can be set using (`spring.jpa.hibernate.properties.<name-of-property>`) or by simply adding a `persistence.xml` or processed in easier ways then trying to do all the manual labor yourself.

Answer (score 2):

OP here.

I seem to have misunderstood that JPA needs an EntityManager instead of a session.

The following configuration works:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJpaConfig
{
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mywebapp");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.example.persistent");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf)
    {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation()
    {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you only need an `EntityManagerFactory` then you only need an `EntityManagerFactory` everything else can still be configured by Spring Boot (datasource, transationmanager). But I really doubt you actually need to to all this manual configuration, imho you are missing knowledge on how to add additional configuration instead.